# CodeIgniter And Image Display in Table

Tags: php, mysql, eclipse, codeigniter

I'm using codeIgniter and uploading image path along with form data in database. The problem that i'm facing is they're not displaying in table. Images are successfully uploaded in the folder and the path is also saved in db but it's not displaying the images.
Code that i've written is below.
In view file:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('welcome/insertion'); ?>
<input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" size="40" maxlength="90" tabindex="3"/>
<input name="saveForm" type="submit" value="Insert Record" class="iconSave" />
```

In controller i write:

```
public function insertion()
{
    $this->load->model('data_maintenance','',TRUE);
    $this->data_maintenance->insertion();
}
```

And finally in model:
    public function insertion()
    {

```
    $config['upload_path'] = 'application/uploads';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|pdf';
    $config['max_size'] = '5000';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
    {
        echo $this->upload->display_errors();


    }
    else
    {
        //$file_data  =   $this->upload->data('image');
        $file_data = $this->upload->data();

        $new_staff = array(
                'agenda_id' => $this->input->post('agenda_id'),
                't_name' => $this->input->post('t_name'),
                'exp' => $this->input->post('exp'),
                'leaves_allow_monthly' => $this->input->post('leaves_allow_monthly'),
                'leaves_allow_annualy' => $this->input->post('leaves_allow_annualy'),
                'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
                'cell_no' => $this->input->post('cell_no'),
                'dob' => $this->input->post('dob'),
                'file' => $file_data['file_name']

        );


    }
    $d="/SampleOOP/application/uploads/" . $new_staff['file'];
    $this->db->set('image', $d);
    //$this->db->insert('teachers_record');


    //$d="/SampleOOP/application/uploads/".$new_staff['file'];
    $this->db->set('teacher_name', $new_staff['t_name']);
    //$this->db->set('image',$d);
    $this->db->insert('teachers_record');

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try `print_r($file_data)` and see what comes back, you can also try: `$file_data['orig_name']`

Or:

```
$file_name = $file_data['file_name'];

$new_staff = array(
        'agenda_id' => $this->input->post('agenda_id'),
        't_name' => $this->input->post('t_name'),
        'exp' => $this->input->post('exp'),
        'leaves_allow_monthly' => $this->input->post('leaves_allow_monthly'),
        'leaves_allow_annualy' => $this->input->post('leaves_allow_annualy'),
        'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
        'cell_no' => $this->input->post('cell_no'),
        'dob' => $this->input->post('dob'),
        'file' => $file_name

);
```

UPDATE, Try:

```
$config['upload_path'] = 'application/uploads';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|pdf';
$config['max_size'] = '5000';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);

Or

$this->load->library('upload');
$config['upload_path'] = 'application/uploads';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|pdf';
$config['max_size'] = '5000';
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

Comment: it says.... Array ( [agenda_id] => [t_name] => ii [exp] => iii [leaves_allow_monthly] => ii [leaves_allow_annualy] => ii [gender] => ii [cell_no] => ii [dob] => i [file] => 10610490_861546163879350_7532429969037978527_n.jpg )

Comment: image is uploaded in the folder plus path is also saved in db.

Comment: Put that way: 'file' => $file_data['file']

Comment: It shows error on undefined variable "file". My main problem is not uploading of image rather the image is not displaying in the table even though it's uploaded in the folder.

Comment: I reviewed your code and you should use: $this->load->library ('upload', $config); or $this->load->library('upload') and $this->upload->initialize($config); I updated the answer above

Comment: I've already load the library in my code but nothing happens i don't know what's the issue with displaying the image in table.